# Version info for App localisation displayed on App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

In `App Store Connect`, which is the default version information displayed on the App Store for the text fields "`What's new in this version`" & "`Promotional Text`" in the localized alternatives?

Is the following assumption correct?

The version information is provided in English in the App's main language "English US" and in Spanish "Spanish (Spain)":

1. Spanish (Spain) as well as all other Spanish variants will use the
   Spanish text that is provided manually.
2. All other App Stores using English or another language will display the English text that has been provided manually.

Or are both text fields being left empty actually don't display anything in the App Store?

I feel like having to copy&paste the English version manually for all localised versions (using only localised keywords) shouldn't be necessary.

If you have tested this or seen the actual behaviour, I'd very much appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from Anand is not correct.

1) For all **required** fields (like description, keywords, what's new etc.) you must insert something for all active languages/localizations over at App Store Connect.

**Example**: If you start version 1.0 with English (en-US) as your primary locale and add Spanish (es-ES) to your version 1.1 you must insert something in the "What's new" section for Spanish. (As for all other required fields) Otherwise App Store Connect won't let you submit the app for review.

App Store Connect *won't validate or check* your translations, so you could translate your general metadata once and "keep" the "What's new" section English, but you must copy & paste the information.

2) **Optional** fields (promotional text, marketing URL etc.) can be left blank or only filled in for one language, but the App Store will not mix and match locales.

**Example**: If you insert a promotional text for English (en-US), which is your primary locale, and none for Spanish (es-ES), the Spanish localization will not display any promotional text.

With regards to when which language is used, check out this paragraph from the [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2):

> For example, if the primary language you select for your app in App Store Connect is English and it’s the only language you provide, your app metadata in all App Store territories appears in English. If you localize your app metadata in French, users whose language setting is French will see the French localization. Users in territories where the App Store supports French but not English also see the French localization. Users can search for your app using localized keywords in all territories where the App Store supports French. If there’s no localization available that matches the language setting, the next most relevant localization is used. In other App Store territories, users see your metadata in the primary language (English in this example).

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. I've now had the possibility to test this with an app of mine being updated and indeed, the localisations behave the way you've described them here. The fact that AppStoreConnect will not accept empty mandatory fields in any localisation when submitting an app should've been a flag already.

Answer (score 0):

If English is the primary language of the app, your assumption is right.

1. Text updated for Spanish will be shown in Spanish App Store.
2. English updated for English(U.S) language will be shown in all other App
   Store since it is the primary language.

We need not copy paste the English version manually for all localized versions. The Primary language text will be automatically updated for all localized versions. It is up to us to change the localized text for other languages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, before I accept it, can you please confirm the following: Regarding 1., You are referring to not only the "Spanish App Store" as in the App Store in Spain, but all App Stores in the Spanish-speaking Countries as they are specified in AppStoreConnect (Mexico, Latin-American Countries etc). a) This is true for not only the "What's new" information but also the "Promotional text" and b) You have either tested this or know it by fact.

Comment: Yes. It applies to Spanish speaking regions and I knew this based on my experience in releasing the apps. All this applies to what’s new . I haven’t explored promotional text.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I will test the promotional text on next release myself, then.